# How I can prevent to change my ip during browse the website by usening selenium pyhthon firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

ther is my code when i visit this site ( https://www.myip.com/) and after 1 minute refresh the site my ip will change , my question is How I can prevent to change my ip during browse the website by usening selenium pyhthon firefox

```
import os
import time

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver

torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe')

time.sleep(5)
binary = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile(r"C:\Users\sam\OneDrive\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9150)
profile.update_preferences()
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, binary)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

#driver.quit()
```

Comment: One of the good question I have come across recently.

Comment: so, do you know the solution for this broblem ?

Comment: I should, however once again configuring tor just for one question is..... :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **You can't**
`Selemium` is definitely **not** a tool for such a things.
Your question is like:
"What T-shirt should I wear in order to prevent the https://www.myip.com/ from changing my PC IP address"?

Comment: But I found this ansewer but i didnot know use it
import stem.process

tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    tor_cmd = PATH_TO_TOR_LAUNCHER,
    config = {
        'SOCKSPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
        'ControlPort': str(CTRL_PORT),
        'DataDirectory': DATA_DIR,
        'GeoIPFile': DATA_DIR + 'geoip',
        'GeoIPv6File': DATA_DIR + 'geoip6',
        'ExitNodes': '{es},{pt}'       # exiting through Spain or Portugal
        }
)

Comment: I don't know what you found and where, Selenium is a tool to make user-like actions via web pages GUI elements. Generally, you can read web elements, click on them etc. with Selenium. That's it.